# Dealing with a scenario in python that requires me to display names and prices (highest to lowest) and cheapest item is free,

Tags: python, function, sorting

This is the scenario I have been given and I'm struggling to complete this as I don't have a great amount of experience in Python

"You have to create a program for an online shop deal where if a customer buys five items they get the fifth free. The program should take in the five products and their cost and then display them by price (highest to lowest). It should then calculate a
total cost discounting the cheapest item and display the total owed."

This is my code currently:

```py
def products():
    for counter in range(5):
        product_name = input("Please enter product name:")
        product_price = float(input("Please enter product price:"))
        return

def sort(product_price):
    product_price = sorted(product_price, reverse=True)
    print(product_price)
    
                                                               
products()
sort(product_price)
```

It would mean a lot if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are creating variables inside a function and then trying to access them outside which will not work in python. Also the functions seem a bit unnecessary to me for something this short. Try something like this:

```
# Create an empty list
items = []

# Get user input for 5 items
for _ in range(0, 5):
    name = input("Item name: ")
    price = float(input("Item price: "))
    items.append({
        "name": name,
        "price": price
    })

# Sort the items by price in reverse
sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda k: k["price"], reverse=True)

# Calculate total of 4 most expensive items
total_cost = 0
for index in range(0, 4):
    total_cost += sorted_items[index]["price"]

# Print the total
print(total_cost)
```

There are loads of ways to solve this, but using a list of dictionaries appealed to me. Hope this makes sense! I'll leave the printing of the prices and rounding decimals up to you.

Comment: Nice, clear code. If any, I would possibly use some functional code for the total sum:

total_cost = sum( map( lambda x: x["price"], si[:4] ) )